# Using BlazingCache open source in Hadoop degrades the performance

Tags: java, performance, hadoop

I try to use an open source namely BlazingCache http://blazingcache.org/ to implement a coordinator cache idea for my application.

So I just use WordCount example https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v2.0 to test this cache library. Here is my whole code:

```
public class WordCount2 {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    //...
    private static Cache<String, String> cache;
    @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
      //...
      initCache();
    }

    private void initCache() {
         CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.put("blazingcache.mode","clustered");        
         properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.connectstring","localhost:1281");
         properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.sessiontimeout","40000");        
         properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.path","/blazingcache");           
         CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager(provider.getDefaultURI(), provider.getDefaultClassLoader(), properties);
         MutableConfiguration<String, String> cacheConfiguration = new MutableConfiguration<>();
         cache = cacheManager.createCache("example", cacheConfiguration);
    }

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //...
        cache.put(word.toString(), one.toString());
      }
    }
  }

  //...
}
```

The problem is at line:

```
cache.put(word.toString(), one.toString());
```

in map function.

When this line is inserted to the code, the performance of whole job degrade suddenly. (I'm using Eclipse to run the WordCount example in local mode).
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, you can try to check your logs and look for "connection events" and Exceptions in blazingcache.xxx loggers.

Please note that a Cache.put must eventually notify other clients which are hosting a copy of the data and this is a network operation. In such a MapReduce jobs it is possible that many clients are holding a reference to the same "word". Remember to close the CacheManager because each CacheManager creates a CacheClient and so it retains resources and receives notifications.

When the underlying CacheClient works in disconnected mode it may slow down because without a connection to the cache server it cannot guarantee the consistency of the cache and so it tried to way for a connection for quite a long time.

I have reproduced you case, you have to edit these lines:

1) you have to "create" the cache only once

```
try {
   cache = cacheManager.createCache("example", cacheConfiguration);
} catch (CacheException alreadyCreated) {                
}
cache = cacheManager.getCache("example");
```

2) do not use a static reference to the cache
3) remove the line which enables discovery of cache servers

```
properties.put("blazingcache.mode", "clustered");
```

With those changes the example code runs very well.

If you want to run in real clustered mode you have to start a zookkeeper cluster and at least one blazingcache server.
Without zookeeper I get this error loop:

> 16/07/08 13:26:14 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:1281. Will not attempt to
>   authenticate using SASL (unknown error) 16/07/08 13:26:14 WARN
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,
>   closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connessione rifiutata  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
>     at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
>   16/07/08 13:26:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local7226039_0001
>   running in uber mode : false 16/07/08 13:26:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: 
>   map 0% reduce 0% 16/07/08 13:26:16 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening
>   socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:1281. Will
>   not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) 16/07/08
>   13:26:16 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null,
>   unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

You should ask for help at blazingcache support mailing lists

Comment: Thanks your answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in local mode (single JVM) that you'd better to remove these lines and try again:

```
properties.put("blazingcache.mode","clustered");        
properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.connectstring","localhost:1281");
properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.sessiontimeout","40000");        
properties.put("blazingcache.zookeeper.path","/blazingcache");
```